subdivision modifier not working properly when rendering
I'm having a problem when rendering this image while using subdivision modifier, on viewport all seems fine but when rendering this happens,when using shade auto smooth it fixed the problem but I don't know why it happened

hello could you please share your file?

Hello and welcome. Could would textually describe the issue, be descriptive summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Avoid using words like "this", instead describe what "it" is. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

The Subdivision Surface Modifier uses different levels for the viewport and render. If you have set the render-value lower than the viewport level it can appear that the surface is less smooth in the render than in the viewport. Change them to the same value and they will look the same.
